# In the word "Scent", is the S or the C silent?

Tags: pronunciation, silent-letters

So I saw a post on a funny pictures site...

"In the word "Scent", is the S or the C silent?"

[image]

In particular, how does the pronunciation of "scent" differ from "cent" and "sent"?

Small audio references would help me in particular.

Comment: the pair "sc" forms a sound in English.  (just like, say "sh" or "ch" or "ck" or many other examples.)  It's a funny poster though!

Comment: Neither. The *s* is the usual, while the *c* is the soft-C, that's all. When was *scent* first used as a noun?

Comment: The only honest answer is: *all* letters in that word are silent. All letters in *all* words are silent. It's spoken language that gets written down, not written language that gets pronounced.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Feel free to edit my question to "How does the pronounciation of scent differ from sent and cent?" if you feel that "silentness" is not objective enough.

Comment: The referenced post is making an attempt at humor. The point is, such a question has no answer, since the distinction is meaningless.

Comment: Yeah, like @Robusto said.  In fact, both the "s" and the "c" are silent, but together they force the "e" to be pronounced with a leading sibilance.  :-) :-)

Comment: @Kris That can't be correct, because otherwise it would be a double length geminate like we find for example in *guests* /gess/ when the /t/ is elided.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to make scents out of Englisc as if it were a science and not scpelling scoup.

Comment: Neither. They're both pronounced.

Comment: From the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=scent) - "late 14c., *sent* "to find the scent of," from Old French *sentir* "to feel, smell, touch, taste; realize, perceive; make love to," from Latin *sentire* " to feel, perceive, sense, discern, hear, see" (see sense (n.)). Originally a hunting term. The -c- appeared 17c., perhaps by influence of *ascent, descent*, etc., or by influence of *science*". So, although my first comment is funnier, it would appear that the *-c-* is silent.

Comment: @Pimgd RegDwight is just being silly and there's no need to edit your question. To answer the question at the end of your post, "scent", "cent", and "sent" are all pronounced exactly the same.

Comment: Huh, @BobJarvis ? Etymonline doesn't seem to say "Neither. They're both pronounced."

Comment: @Araucaria It indeed is extended length, though not quite double, even as it is in *science.*

Answer (score 57, accepted):

User [dawnhunter](http://www.reddit.com/user/dawnhunter) of [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/) [writes](http://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/2e57mx/in_the_word_scent_is_it_the_s_or_the_c_that_is/cjw7rw4) in the [/r/Showerthoughts/](http://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/) thread called [In the word "scent", is it the S or the C that is silent?](http://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/2e57mx/in_the_word_scent_is_it_the_s_or_the_c_that_is/):

> Here's what a google search brings up:
>
> late Middle English (denoting the sense of smell): from Old French sentir ‘perceive, smell,’ from Latin sentire . The addition of -c- (in the 17th century) is unexplained.
>
> So the c is silent and also shouldn't really be there.

Also, further down the thread, another comment says:

> The 'c' was probably added because that was the style at the time.
>
> Originally a hunting term. The -c- appeared 17c., perhaps by influence of ascent, descent, etc., or by influence of science. This was a tendency in early Modern English, also in scythe and for a time threatening to make scite and scituate.

Stating [this entry at etymonline.com as the source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=scent)

Comment: Whoa, "scite" and "scituate" sound like murdering language...

Comment: Lucky they didn't make it Scmeg-head eh Rimmer? ;-)

Comment: @Pimgd Here in New England [Scituate is a reality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scituate).

Comment: If I had to guess, the -c- appeared as a result of a spurious etymology from the Latin *scire* ‘to know,’ cf. [the archaic French spelling of *sçavoir* for *savoir*, ‘to know,’](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/savoir#French) which actually derives from the Latin *sapere*.

Comment: "sentir" is not Old French, it is everyday modern French with the same meaning.

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru *Sentir* is also Old French. The Normans certainly didn't bring *modern* French to England...

Comment: I won't downvote, but I don't agree with this answer. The C was added, sure, but that doesn't make it the silent letter. I guess I'll actually leave an answer.

Comment: @emodendroket: And so is [*scite*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciTE), sort of (with funny capitalization). It actually happens to be the editor I use most. Interestingly, its pronunciation also happens to be, to my knowledge, the *only* topic for which something I wrote spent any time as the top Google hit (which it no longer is, but it's still on the first page of results).

Comment: @JohnY Such Google fame can be very temporary - or unjustified: My personal website had been extremely famous for "cheap razor blades" for an extended period of time. If the Google webmaster tools hadn't told me so, I would never have guessed anything like that (a very minor paragraph on a sub-sub-page mentioned a method for cutting cardboard)

Comment: Pity that this answer leaves the door wide open for the follow-up question about _science_. And this answer does not explain that _c_.

Comment: This is accurate considering how the *c* in **Sclera** is not silent.

Answer (score 20):

Speakers of the Queen's English have no trouble with this; if neither letter in "scent"were silent, it would be pronounced like the beginning of "sceptic". Actually, the C is silent, making the word (to all but Professor Higgins-level phoneticians) identical to "sent". Coincidentally, there is a funny little foreign coin, *cent*, that is pronounced the same way.

(I understand the question may be harder for those across the Atlantic; that is just one of the many disavantages of having left the British Empire all those years ago.)

Comment: *... would be pronounced like the beginning of "sceptic:"* why not like *science?*

Comment: I know how to pronounce SCIENCE! and I know that removing the c leads to a weird pronunciation where it sounds more like "see-ense". For me the answer "it's like the word science" helps me to understand it better.

Comment: @Kris: because *science* has a silent letter. That's rather the point.

Comment: @TimLymington So which letter in *science* is silent?  :)

Comment: Yeah but *science* is *sci-ence* right? There's a pretty clear difference between "si" and "sci", I'd say one would be like "see" and the other one like "sai".

Comment: "to all but Professor Higgins-level phoneticians" - oxforddictionaries.com has *sɛnt* for both **scent** and **sent** - is there anyone who would have these different??

Comment: Even accepting the notion of ‘silent letters’ (as Reg points out, _all_ letters are really silent—there is no one-to-one correspondence between written letters and phonemes or phones in a word), this is just wrong. A c before a front vowel would not be expected to be pronounced /k/; this is only the case in a few words where the letter-to-sound correspondence is even lower than on average: _sceptic, ceilidh_. The default interpretion of ‹ce› is that it likely represents /se/.

Comment: @AakashM No, no one. _Scent_, _sent_, and _cent_ are all pronounced **exactly the same** in every single dialect of English that I have ever heard the words pronounced in.

Comment: @Pimgd _Science_ and _sience_ (if it existed) would most likely both be pronounced the same: [ˈsɑɪəns]. ‹si› and ‹sci› and ‹ci› all default to representing /si/ or /siː/, depending on the word and the context, though it is true that only ‹si› would normally be used to represent /zi/ or /ziː/.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I pronounce sent/scent/cent differently; the soft *c* is pronounced with the jaw still, lower jaw pulled in, pushing the air through the space between the teeth.  The *s* is pronounced by sliding the lower jaw outwards while holding the tip of the tongue up towards the top of the mouth, resulting in a much softer sound.  The *sc* in *scent* and *science* is a combination of the two (i.e., neither letter is silent).  Now, maybe this is just my weird affectation, maybe it's a Canadianism, I don't know.

Comment: @Pimgd: Why do you have a problem pronouncing "sience" the same as "science"? At the risk of opening a recursive self-referential vortex, how do you pronounce "silent"? "see-lent"? Or with the first syllable (si-) rhyming with "die", "lie", "pie", and "tie" (and like "bi-" in "biannual", "binary", "biology", and "bivalve")?

Comment: @Scott I don't know anymore TT_TT English is hard and I have no idea how and why my mouth produces words... at least my mouth knows. Or would that be my vocal chords?

Comment: @Tim: Your answer is a red herring. According to Google, "skeptic" is about 10 times as common as "sceptic"; even [Stack Exchange](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com) spells it with a "k". Most words containing "sce" are pronounced "se" rather than "ske"; e.g., "scene" (and "obscene"), "abscess", "ascend"/"ascent"/"descend"/"descent", and "scepter".

Comment: @AmeliaBR I suspect that is your own weird affectation. I have never seen any description of or myself heard any dialect of English that distinguished more unvoiced sibilants than /s/ and /ʃ/, and in all the words we’re discussing here, plain old /s/ is used. No difference whatsoever. Their identical pronunciation is why some words can be spelt differently with no problems in different orthographies: _offence/offense_, _defence/defense_, etc.

Comment: @Scott, I'm pretty sure Tim's reference to "the Queen's English" was an allusion to the differences between North American (*skeptic*) and British (*sceptic*) orthography; see for example [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sceptic), which also lists the *k* version as an archaic form. Your Google search, and Stack Exchange's own usage, reflect the American spelling.

Comment: Tim, There are no silent letters in *science* either :) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193548/in-the-word-scent-is-the-s-or-the-c-silent/193552?noredirect=1#comment405093_193548

Comment: This appears to be a weird instance of dialect-warring? I realise the coda is probably typically-British humour, but, ah, we're *not* all Brits here and the joke is flat.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie A schism? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/schism

Comment: `sceptic` versus `skeptic` - despite being a native mumbler of the American language (such as it is :-}) even *I* shudder in horror at `skeptic`. That's Just SO Wrong!

Answer (score 3):

Neither is silent.

The "s" and the "c" together make a softer "s" sound. Compared to the words "sent" and "cent", the word "scent" sounds more like "sscent."

Similar to the words "ascent" and "assent", where assent has a harder and faster sound.

Comment: Hmm, another Canadian who believes that sent/scent/cent are pronounced differently; perhaps [it isn't just my affectation after all](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193548/in-the-word-scent-is-the-s-or-the-c-silent/193552?noredirect=1#comment405212_193552).  That said, I'm not sure that *ascent* vs *assent* is a good comparison: that could be interpretted as the difference between *a-scent* and *as-sent*, the two separate *s* sounds in the second word blurring into the stronger hissing sound.

Comment: Approach a random person, speak any permutation of the phrase "Cent sent scent." (e.g. alternately "Sent scent cent."), and then ask them how the phrase is written. Do you really think they'll be able to naturally (i.e. without prefacing with a discussion about how "sc" is/might be pronounced) determine which of the three words is spelled "scent"? I'm inclined to think not.

Comment: As Canadian who doesn't hear this difference, I condescend to dissent. Perhaps it's regional, perhaps it's a hypercorrection. :)

Comment: @talrnu I think all the remains is for you to carry out your experiment

Comment: I think an even more telling experiment would be to take one of these people who claim to have a distinction, record them reading an extended passage which uses all the different forms a few times, extract the individual words from the passage, and ask them to identify which extracted word is which. I'd be willing to bet they'll be statistically no better than random.

Answer (score 3):

Neither letter is silent. Both make the same sound /s/ And when two identical sounds are put together in the same word English, they are almost always said as if they were one sound. So we say [s] instead of [ss].

The fact that the C was added later is irrelevant, as it was likely added because it would not change the pronunciation of the word.

Silent letters in English were usually at one time pronounced (whether in English or the originating language). The P in pneumonia is silent because we don't say /pn/ at the beginning of words. The W in write is silent because we can't say /wr/.

Analyzing a letter as being silent is more of a last resort thing, what you do when no other rule of English orthography will work.

Comment: Oh, I dunno. A *penknife* seems to have two different (geminated) /n/ sounds in it to me.

Comment: Some silent letters were just added in English and were never pronounced in any language; but in most cases, you're right of course.

Comment: I confirm what @JanusBahsJacquet said. The r-wr distinction was present in Old English but I think it was gone by Middle English already. The difference was that r wasn't "rounded" while wr was. As for scent, [see here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scent).

Comment: Not all silent letters were originally pronounced. "Debt" was never pronounced /debt/; although borrowed from Old French "dette", the "b" was added (restored?) to resemble the original source word, Latin "debitum".

Comment: @tchrist Yes, it does, but it's an exception due to it being a compound word. It is not uncommon for doubled consonants to be geminated between words.

Comment: I hope my edits have addressed all the complaints.

Answer (score 2):

"Sc" in "scent" or "science" is used as a consonant digraph (two consonant combined to make one sound); therefore, neither are silent (they are being used as a consonant digraph). "Sc" in "scare" is used as a consonant blend (two consonants combined to make two different sounds), so the two different usages can't be compared effectively.